# broken links to css/js with Jekyll on local version

Tags: github, jekyll

I use [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) to build my blog, here is the [code on github](https://github.com/denisjacquemin/denisjacquemin.github.com)

when I generate the code with the command `jekyll pygments`, it builds the site in the `_site` directory.

when I open the _site/index.html page in a browser, the css/js links are broken because they looks like the following

```
/css/style.css
```

to make it works the links should not begin with the /

what should I do to test the site on my local machine with working links to css/js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i found the solution:

Running Jekyll with its standalone server

```
jekyll --auto --server
```

and then access in the browser at

```
http://localhost:4000
```

Comment: In case anyone comes across this in the future: the command is now `jekyll serve`.